# Default value for generic data structure

Tags: generics, scala, default-value

I would like to write a `SparseVector[T]` class where `T` can be a double, an int or a boolean.

The class will not be backed by an array (because I want a sparse data structure) but I have seen that when I build an empty array of an `AnyVal` type, the elements are initialized to the default value. For instance:

```
 scala> new Array[Int](10)
 res0: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

 scala> new Array[Boolean](10)
 res1: Array[Boolean] = Array(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)

 scala> new Array[Double](10) 
 res2: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

How can I include this default value in my class ? The behaviour I would like to get is:

```
val v = new SparseVector[Double](100)
println( v(12) ) // should print '0.0'
val w = new SparseVector[Boolean](100)
println( v(85) ) // should print 'false'
```

Thanks

Comment: This is interesting. C# provides a "default" keyword takes a type and provides the default value for that type. It treats value and reference types differently, so default(int) is 0 while default(SomeClass) is null. I wonder if scala has a similar construct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could leverage the fact that Scala already provides you a way of getting the default value of a type. When you write `var x: Int = _`, this initialises `x` to `0`. Similar for all `AnyVal` types. All `AnyRef` types are initialised to `null`.

Bearing that in mind, you could rewrite your sparse vector class as following:

```
class SparseVector[T](val size: Int) {
  import scala.collection.mutable.Map

  private var default: T = _
  private[this] val storage = Map[Int, T]() 

  def apply(key: Int) = 
    if(key < size)
      storage.getOrElse(key, default)
    else 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index "  + key + " out of bounds")

  def update(key: Int, value: T) { storage(key) = value }
}
```

Now code like the following works as expected:

```
scala> val b = new SparseVector[Boolean](10)
b: SparseVector[Boolean] = SparseVector@cfd22a

scala> b(1)
res20: Boolean = false

scala> b(1) = true

scala> b(1)
res22: Boolean = true

scala> val i = new SparseVector[Int](10)
i: SparseVector[Int] = SparseVector@1813c12

scala> i(1)
res23: Int = 0

scala> i(1) = 10

scala> i(1)
res25: Int = 10

scala> i(10)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index 10 out of bounds
```

A couple of improvements I might make to this class:

- Have a `toString` method printing the collection in a reasonable way
- Provide a companion object which can change the default value of the vector if required (see the code below).

```
object SparseVector {
  def apply[T](size: Int) = new SparseVector[T](size)
  def apply[T](size: Int, default: T) = {
    val result = new SparseVector[T](size)
    result.default = default

    result
  }
}
```

Now this works:

```
scala> val b = SparseVector[Boolean](10, true)
b: SparseVector[Boolean] = SparseVector@126f29f

scala> b(4)
res28: Boolean = true

scala> val i = SparseVector[Int](10, 42)
i: SparseVector[Int] = SparseVector@b9979b

scala> i(3)
res30: Int = 42
```

**EDIT:** The code I have written works with Scala 2.7.6.final. [Mitch Blevins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164075/mitch-blevins) has pointed out that the code yields `null` as a default value for `AnyVal` types when run with Scala 2.8r.19890. As explained in the comments, this should not be possible as `Null` is not a subtype of `AnyVal`.<s>The general idea should be similar if using 2.8, as `var b: Boolean = _` should still give you the default value of the `Boolean` type. The usage of collections to store the sparse vector might be different, but as I said in the comment, I am not familiar with the 2.8 collection redesign.</s>

**EDIT2:** ... the `null` behaviour should not be possible, but unfortunately it is. Doing some [more research into the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853397/unexpected-scala-default-values-behavior/1853837#1853837) it seems that due to type erasure the field `default` *always* gets initialised to `null`. And after that... weirdness ensues. See [Mitch's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853397/unexpected-scala-default-values-behavior) for a discussion and some bear-bones code reproducing the problem.

Things I have tried and failed in order to make the code work as it should:

- `null.asInstanceOf[T]` - nope, Java doesn't have reified generics. This still yields `null`
- `@specialised` - nope, it seems that even if the compiler generates specialised code for primitives, you still get the null behaviour
- Casting the result to an `AnyVal`, which should not be `null`. Nope. Still `null`.

So conceptually, my solution should work. But it doesn't due to very strange behaviour which I have [reported](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2776) in the Scala Trac.

See also [this blog post](http://dzhigital.blogspot.com/2009/03/nullable-anyval-in-scala.html) for a nice discussion of `null`able `AnyVal`s.

-- Flaviu Cipcigan

Comment: Using 2.8r.19890, this returns null as the default for Booleans (or any of the AnyVals)

Comment: @Mitch Hm... that must be a bug then. Logically, an `AnyVal` type should not be `null`. The type of `null` is `Null`, which is a bottom type of `AnyRef`. If you try to assign `null` to an `AnyVal` type you should get a compile error - `val b: Boolean = null` yields a type mismatch (found `Null`, required `Boolean`). Or it might be due to the collection redesign (with which I am not familiar) - I suspect that the `getOrElse` method behaves strangely in that case. Try `var b: Boolean = _` in the Scala REPL. It should default to `false` :).

Comment: The behavior that led to my confusion is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853397/scala-default-values-behavior

Comment: So if I use `private var default: T = null.asInstanceOf[T]` it will be compatible with scala 2.7 and 2.8 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. See my revised answer for a short discussion.

Answer (score 7):

You could add an implicit argument as a second parameter to the constructor:

```
class SparseVector[A](size: Int) (implicit default: () => A) {
  private var storage = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, A]()
  def apply(i: Int) = storage.getOrElse(i, default())
  def update(i: Int, v: A) = storage.update(i, v)
}

implicit def strDefault(): String = "default"
```

And provide implicits for the types you care about.  This also allows callers to provide their own defaults, by passing their own default values in:

```
val sparseWithCustomDefault = new SparseVector[String](10) (() => "dwins rules!");
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I am not comfortable with `implicit` parameter. I am afraid of colliding definitions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a manifest to get the same default as for `Array`, which avoids the need to provide your own implicits. Borrowing the rest of the code again from David Winslow,

```
class SparseVector[T](size: Int)(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) {
    private val default = manifest.newArray(1)(0)
    private var storage = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, T]()
    def apply(i: Int) = storage.getOrElse(i, default)
    def update(i: Int, v: T) = storage.update(i, v)
}
```

Then just,

```
val v = new SparseVector[Int](100)
println( v(12) ) // prints '0'
```

etc.

Comment: Looks like a dirty hack at first, but this solution avoids importing implicits.

Answer (score 0):

Re-using David's SparseVector class, you could use something like this:

```
class SparseVector[T](size: Int, default: T = 0) {
  private var storage = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, T]()
  def apply(i: Int) = storage.getOrElse(i, default)
  def update(i: Int, v: T) = storage.update(i, v)
}

object SparseVector {
  implicit def svInt2String(i: Int) = "default"
  implicit def svInt2Boolean(i: Int = false
}
```

You need to Import the implicits, which is a shame, but this gives you:-

```
import SparseVector._    

val v = new SparseVector[Int](100)
println( v(12) ) // prints '0'
val w = new SparseVector[Double](100)
println( w(12) ) // prints '0.0'
val x = new SparseVector[Boolean](100)
println( x(85) ) // prints 'false'
val y = new SparseVector[String](100)
println( y(85) ) // prints 'default'
```